# routing does not works on production for "blog/ :page"

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am learning angular and is trying to build a blogging website for myself. The website works as expected on my local system when I run it using

> `ng serve`

But on the other hand when I created a build of it and uploaded it on production using

> `ng build --prod`

The routing does not works. I added the code in `.htaccess` on my server

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

The routing started working for

> http://www.atest.co.in/blog/

but still fails for

> http://www.atest.co.in/blog/Manual_Testing%2FIs_Manual_Testing_Dying

the routing set for the above are as follows:

```
  {
    path: 'blog',
    component: BlogComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'blog/:page',
    component: BlogComponent
  }
```

Though the later one works fine on `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

According to your code, it's just static html file load. But the route in your question has a `/` in the file name which is encoded as `%2F`. I Think it makes an error when route directly. If you access http://www.atest.co.in/blog/ first and then click link in the sidebar, you would get the page.

**Remove the %2F character in file name**, it would work.

Comment: That did not worked. Could you please have a look at my code and let me know if something is wrong with my code? https://github.com/vibhorgoyal18/atest-blog

Comment: But it works perfectly fine in development mode. Isn't it something that should be handled at server side, rather than at code side?

Comment: Thanks, removing %2F helped. It worked. Thank you very much.